# Is it acceptable to have a surrogate/primary key of one table be the primary/foreign key of another table?

Tags: database-design, foreign-key, surrogate-key

For my purposes I'm trying to apply this to Microsoft SQL, but would like to know if there are restrictions for other DBMS regarding this.

I don't know how to represent UML as ascii characters so if someone has a tool suggestion to do so please add in comments.

Example of the scenario below.  Note that I'm using composite keys.

```
building
------------------------------------
+ buildingFullName:String(30) <<PK>>
+ buildingId:Int <<SK>> <<PK>>

buildingRoom
------------------------------------
+ buildingId:Int <<PK>>  <<FK>>
+ roomNumber:String(10) <<PK>>
+ roomId:Int <<PK>> <<SK>>

buildingRoomAsset
-------------------------------------
+ roomId:Int <<PK>> <<FK>>
+ roomAsset:String(9) <<PK>> <<SK>>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using composite primary keys, your foreign key references would also need to be composite keys.  If the primary key of `building` is `(buildingId, buildingFullName)` then `buildingRoom` would need to have both a `buildingId` and a `buildingFullName` that would be the foreign key to `building`.  Similarly, if `(buildingId, buildingRoom, roomId)` is the primary key of `buildingRoom`, you would need all three of those columns in `buildingRoomAsset` in order to create the foreign key.  Defining the foreign keys this way doesn't make sense.

If you are adding a surrogate key to the table, you would almost always want to define that column and that column alone as the primary key of the table.  You can add additional unique constraints to ensure that things like the `buildingFullName` are unique within the table.  Adding the `buildingFullName` to the primary key not only forces the `buildingFullName` to be pulled through to all the child tables, making it much more difficult to update the data, it means that you can have many buildings with the same name which seems unlikely to be what you're after.

Additionally, I would strongly suspect that you want an `asset` table that stores information about assets and then a `roomAsset` table that maps a `roomId` to one or more `assetId` values.  That will make life much easier when an asset gets moved from one room to another among other use cases.

If it were me

```
building
------------------
+ buildingId <<SK>> <<PK>>
+ buildingFullName 

room
------------------
+ roomId <<SK>> <<PK>>
+ buildingId <<FK>>
+ roomNumber

asset
------------------
+ assetId <<SK>> <<PK>>
+ assetName

roomAsset
------------------
+ roomAssetId <<SK>> <<PK>>
+ roomId <<FK>>
+ assetId <<FK>>
```

Comment: I see the point about difficulty to update information with my initial design.  I had forgotten about the Unique constraint which is probably then what I will end up using to maintain normalization.